# Find all integer solutions of $(a+b+3)^2+2ab=3ab(a+2)(b+2)$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

**Here is another number theory problem that I am not able to do**

Find all integer solutions of $$(a+b+3)^2+2ab=3ab(a+2)(b+2)$$
My attempt$:$

On expanding we get,

$$b^2+4ab+6b+a^2+6a+9=3a^2b^2+6a^2b+6ab^2+12ab$$ or $$-6ab^2+b^2-8ab+6b+a^2+6a+9=3a^2b^2+6a^2b$$ or $$-6ab^2+b^2-8ab+6b+a^2+6a+9-3a^2b^2-6a^2b=0$$ or $$\left(1-3b^2-6b\right)a^2+\left(-6b^2-8b+6\right)a+b^2+6b+9=0$$ or $$a=\frac{-\left(-6b^2-8b+6\right)\pm \sqrt{\left(-6b^2-8b+6\right)^2-4\left(1-3b^2-6b\right)\left(b^2+6b+9\right)}}{2\left(1-3b^2-6b\right)}$$ or $$a=\frac{-\left(-6b^2-8b+6\right)\pm \:4\sqrt{3}\left(b+1\right)\sqrt{b\left(b+2\right)}}{2\left(1-3b^2-6b\right)};\quad \:b\ne \:-\frac{3+2\sqrt{3}}{3},\:b\ne \frac{2\sqrt{3}-3}{3}$$ and after further solving $$a=\frac{3b^2+4b-3+2\sqrt{3}b\sqrt{b\left(b+2\right)}+2\sqrt{3}\sqrt{b\left(b+2\right)}}{1-3b^2-6b}$$ and $$a=\frac{3b^2+4b-3-2\sqrt{3}b\sqrt{b\left(b+2\right)}-2\sqrt{3}\sqrt{b\left(b+2\right)}}{1-3b^2-6b}$$ where $b\ne \:-\frac{3+2\sqrt{3}}{3},\:b\ne \frac{2\sqrt{3}-3}{3}$

So, now I can assign some integer values to $a$ and check if that value of $a$ is giving some integer values of $b$ or not. Like if $a=0$ then $b=-3$. But I think it is merely hit and trial because this thing can also apply to the original equation. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: As a cheap observation, if $p$ is a prime dividing $a$, then $p$ must divide $b+3$.  Similarly, if $p$ divides $b$ then $p$ divides $a+3$. In particular, $\gcd(a,b)$ must be a power of $3$ (could be $1$ of course).

Comment: You can try to define $S=a+b$, $P=ab$, and solve for $S,P$ and then write the quadratic eq $z^2-Sz+P=0$, $z_1=a, z_2=b$ ore $z_1=b, z_2=a$.

Comment: I solved the quadratic equation and I got the value of $S$ in terms of $P$ but what to do now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let x=a+1, y = b+1, so

$(x+y+1)^2 + 2(x-1)(y-1) = 3(x^2-1)(y^2-1)$.

The right hand side is quite obviously larger when |x|, |y| >= 3. Finding solutions for x=-2, -1, 0, 1, 2 are easy to find.

Answer (score 1):

If $S=a+b$, $P=ab$ we have
$$S^2-6(P-1)S-(3P^2+10P-9)=0\rightarrow$$
$$S_{1,2}=3(P-1)\pm2\sqrt{\Delta}$$
$$\Delta=P(3P-2)$$
Now, we must find $P_i$ such as $\Delta$ be a square: $\Delta=K^2$. That is a difficult. I found only
$P_1=0\rightarrow\Delta=0\rightarrow S=-3$

$P_2=1\rightarrow\Delta=1\rightarrow S=\pm2$

$P_2=9\rightarrow\Delta=225\rightarrow S=24\pm15$

Now, for each pear $(S, P)$ solve $x^2-Sx+P=0$.

I don't know a theorem from the number theory to find all roots of the eq.
$$P(3P-2)=K^2$$
One attempt is

$$3P^2-2P=K^2\rightarrow 2P(P-1)=(K-P)(K+P)$$
but is not easier.

Comment: also $P=-2$ is I think a solution

Comment: @Vasile FYI, you can solve $P(3P−2)=K^2$ by: $3P^2−2P=K^2$, $(3P)^2−6P=3K^2$, $(3P)^2−6P+1=3K^2+1$, $(3P−1)^2−3K^2=1$. This is a standard [Pell's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation), with the linked page showing how to determine its *infinite* # of integral solutions. However, note the OP's equation for $a$ has limits of $\frac{3±2\sqrt{3}}{−3}$ as $b \to \pm\infty$. Thus, for *integral* values of $b$, there are very few integral values of $a$, and due to symmetry, with $a$ and $b$ switched around, also few integral values of $b$, so $P$'s range is very limited as well.

Comment: so we can substitute the values of $P$ as they are very less